# SQL Server query help - Related hashtags

Tags: sql-server, database

I have been racking my brains on this one for some time, so through it was about time to ask for some help.

I have a product database, each product has a number of hashtags associated with it. I want to be able to pull out related hashtags.

Let me take you through an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ProductID int, Hashtag varchar(30))

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  1 ,'toys')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  1 ,'lego')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  1 ,'construction')

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  2 ,'toys')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  2 ,'lego')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  2 ,'lego-city')

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  3 ,'clothing')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  3 ,'womens')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  3 ,'jeans')

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  4 ,'clothing')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  4 ,'mens')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  4 ,'tops')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  4 ,'t-shirts')

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  5 ,'clothing')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  5 ,'mens')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  5 ,'tops')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  5 ,'vests')
```

What I want to be able to do is select a Hashtag,  for example "toys", then pull out all other hashtags that have a relationship (via the productId).

This is the results set that should be returned when querying "toys":

```
hashtag, count
lego, 2
construction, 1
lego-city, 1
```

Any help or ideas on how to go about implementing this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c050f/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  Product_id int,
  hashtag varchar(25)
)


insert into YourTable values
(   1,          'toys         '),
(   1,          'lego         '),
(   1,          'construction '),
(   2,          'toys         '),
(   2,          'lego         '),
(   3,          'lego         '),
(   2,          'lego-city    ')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T1.hashtag,
       count(*)  as [count]
from YourTable as T1
where exists (
             select *
             from YourTable as T2 
             where T2.hashtag = 'toys' and
                   T1.Product_id = T2.Product_id
             ) and
      T1.hashtag <> 'toys'
group by T1.hashtag
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c050f/1/0)**:

```
|       HASHTAG | COUNT |
|---------------|-------|
| construction  |     1 |
| lego          |     2 |
| lego-city     |     1 |
```

Comment: I think you have nailed it ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select hashtag,count(hashtag) as count from #product_hashtags group by hashtag
```

Comment: This would give me the results for all the product_hashtags table, however it does not help with finding hashtags that are related to just "toys"

Comment: just add where condition => where hashtag='toys'

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ProductID int, Hashtag varchar(30))

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  1 ,'toys')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  1 ,'lego')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  1 ,'construction')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  2 ,'toys')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  2 ,'lego')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  2 ,'lego-city')


SELECT * FROM #Test


SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Hashtag, COUNT(ProductID) Counter FROM #Test
GROUP BY Hashtag)  as x
where x.Hashtag <> 'toys'
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Not quite, as there may be other products in the table, for example:

Comment: INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  3 ,'clothing')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  3 ,'womens')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  3 ,'jeans')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  4 ,'cars')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  4 ,'vechicle')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(  4 ,'rental')

Comment: Then give us a more relevant example and more information about the table and info from the table.

Comment: these should not be returned in the results, it should only be hashtags that are related to "toys" not, all hashtags except for "toys"

Comment: I have made changed to the question, sorry for not providing enough info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query below:

```
SELECT Hashtag, COUNT(Hashtag) 
FROM #Test 
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM #Test WHERE Hashtag = 'toys')
     AND Hashtag <> 'toys'
GROUP BY Hashtag
```